# Parallels doesn't open the installation file

Tags: virtualization

I tried to create a virtual machine with parallels, but the iso file is not readable by parallels that gives this message: not possible to detect the operative system

Comment: Have you verified the checksum of the ISO you downloaded? If you are unsure how to do this, there is a [guide on the elementary website](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#verify-your-download).

Answer (score 1):

Telling Parallels to 'proceed anyway' and manually selecting Ubuntu Linux as the operating system seems to work.